# How to access Docker desktop Files on a Windows Machine

Tags: docker-desktop

I'm trying to do something that I thought was a bit basic - access a Linux machines files from docker desktop.

I found some old documentation for docker that looks like it would do the job https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c - but I cannot find any of these settings in docker desktop.

Ideas?

Comment: So, you're running Docker Desktop on Windows and trying to share local files with Linux containers?

Comment: @razcor  No other way around.  I just want to get access to the files on the Linux containers.

Comment: Ok, are you using the legacy hyper-v VM or WSL2?

Comment: I'm guessing hyper-v..?  It says You don't have any WSL 2 distro. Please convert a WSL 1 distro to WSL 2, or install a new distro and it will appear here.

Comment: We need to be sure. Please, go to Settings --> General: Use the WSL 2 based engine is flagged?

Comment: Yes, Use the WSL 2 based engine is ticked there!

Comment: Ok, it seems to me that you're in the actual version of Docker Desktop. which is best used with WSL 2 integration, BUT, you're not using this integration...and you're referring to old documentation, better suited for the hyper-v VMs, mainly used in past Docker Desktop versions. I recommend you to use the WSL 2 integration. To find out how, first go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha. Then I will put the proper answer.to your question.